# OpenCL: How does one select the GPU in a context

Tags: opencl

I have selected my context from multiple GPU Devices as such below:

```
type = platforms[0].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);
if(type == CL_SUCCESS)
{
    //Create context and access device names
    cl::Context ctx_(devices);
    context = ctx_;
    gpuDevices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
    for(i=0; i<gpuDevices.size(); i++) {
        deviceName = gpuDevices[i].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>();
        queues.emplace_back(cl::CommandQueue(context, gpuDevices[i], CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE));
        op::log("Adding " + deviceName + " to queue");
    }
}
else if(type == CL_INVALID_DEVICE_TYPE || type == CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Error: GPU Invalid Device or Device not found");
}
break;
```

However, when I create a `cl::Buffer`, it only allows me to pass in one context. How does one select which GPU the memory gets created to.

The constructor of cl::Buffer is

```
Buffer(
        const Context& context,
        cl_mem_flags flags,
        ::size_t size,
        void* host_ptr = NULL,
        cl_int* err = NULL)
```

As you can see it only takes in 1 context, and I can't select my GPU

Comment: A command queue serves only 1 gpu. When you enqueue "read/write buffer" to one of them, they do operation on the gpu of that command queue. This means you need 2 command queues.

Comment: yeah but when i create a new cl::Buffer which gpu does it get copied to

Comment: Buffers can travel anywhere inside of their context. You decide how they do it. Sometimes its even implicit. You can directly issue a buffer write command as soon as its created to be sure it is updated on those devices. Easiest way to know is having 1 context per device. But this means they can communicate only through RAM or by migration command. Using only 1 context for whole pc can optimize things for you which makes it harder to predict whats where. Actually it may be even a lazy allocation until you really use it. It can even have a mirror image on RAM for making copying faster.

Comment: But you can try CL_MEM_HOST_NO_ACCESS flag to be sure it doesn't live on RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a buffer for a context, which is shared between multiple devices, the buffer is "shared" between these devices, so you can execute commands on both of them using the same `cl_mem` object. Whether the *memory* to hold this buffer is actually allocated on both devices is implementation defined. The OpenCL driver may defer an actual allocation until the buffer is needed by a command executing on a particular device, and usually it is smart enough to do this, but it really depends on the hardware and the implementation details.

Basically, you have 2 options:

1. Check your OpenCL vendor documentation on how the runtime performs a memory allocation for a shared context.
2. Create a separate `cl::Context` for each device.

Answer (score 0):

Even in contexts with just one device, buffer objects may be resident on both the device and the host. If you fill the buffer using `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` this will take place on a specific command queue, and thus be associated with a specific device. It would stand to reason that most implementations will in this case allocate memory on the device corresponding to the queue and use its DMA engine to fill the buffer.

You don't have any lower level control than this in OpenCL, however.

So if you keep using the same buffer on different queues with different devices, depending on the access mode and how the implementation is written, there might be multiple copies floating around, or the implementation keeps moving the memory. Profiling will tell you whether you're better off with separate contexts or a shared one.